# d3.max(...) in Typescript returns a string

Tags: typescript, d3.js

The  d3.min/max function is returning a `string` instead of a `number`.

```
var nonEmptySets = [];
        this.data.forEach(function(ds) { //data: Array<Array<[number, number]>>
            if(ds && ds.length > 0) {
                nonEmptySets.push(ds);
            }
        })

var max = d3.max(nonEmptySets[0], function(d) { return d[1]; }); //max: string
```

I know i can cast the value of max into a `number` but i don't understand why the function returns a `string`.

Comment: What is the definition of `nonEmptySets`. The definition of max I see will return the same type as you return from the callback you pass in so whatever the type of `d[1]` is will be the return type of `max` (because generics)

Comment: How does your nonEmptySets[0] object looks like?

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem.

After digging into the source code of `@types/d3` I found there are 4 overloads of `d3.max`:

```
/**
 * Return the maximum value in the array of strings using natural order.
 */
export function max(array: ArrayLike<string>): string | undefined;

/**
 * Return the maximum value in the array of numbers using natural order.
 */
export function max<T extends Numeric>(array: ArrayLike<T>): T | undefined;

/**
 * Return the maximum value in the array using natural order and a projection function to map values to strings.
 */
export function max<T>(array: ArrayLike<T>, accessor: (datum: T, index: number, array: ArrayLike<T>) => string | undefined | null): string | undefined;

/**
 * Return the maximum value in the array using natural order and a projection function to map values to easily-sorted values.
 */
export function max<T, U extends Numeric>(array: ArrayLike<T>, accessor: (datum: T, index: number, array: ArrayLike<T>) => U | undefined | null): U | undefined;
```

The reason is that `d3.max` does not know the type of data you pass in, so it tries to fit it in the third case, which returns `string | undefined`.

So if you wish to provide an accessor and expect `max` to return a new data type that is returned by the accessor, you should

- either provide types for the first argument of `d3.max` like this:

  ```
  var nonEmptySets: Array<Array<[number, number]>> = [];
  ```
- or override `T` and `U` like this:

  ```
  var max = d3.max<[number, number], number>(nonEmptySets[0], function(d) { return d[1]; 
  });
  ```

Then you get `max: number`.

Answer (score -2):

D3.max doesn't do any type cast. If you feed string it will return string.

> In addition, elements are compared using natural order rather than numeric order. For example, the maximum of the strings [“20”, “3”] is “3”, while the maximum of the numbers [20, 3] is 20.

[d3-array](https://github.com/d3/d3-array)